# Prove: $E[|XY|] \le \sqrt{E[X^2] + E[Y^2]}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Prove: $E[|XY|] \le \sqrt{E[X^2] + E[Y^2]}$

Starting with:

$$E\Bigg[\Big(\alpha~|X| - |Y|\Big)^2\Bigg] \ge 0$$

$$E\Big[\alpha^2~|X|^2\Big] - 2~\alpha~ E\Big[~|XY|~\Big] + E\Big[Y^2\Big] \ge 0$$

$$\alpha^2 ~E\Big[X^2\Big] - 2~ \alpha~ E\Big[~|XY|~\Big] + E\Big[Y^2\Big] \ge 0$$

**I'm not sure what they did to get to the next step:**

$$E\Bigg[~2~ \Big|XY\Big|~ \Bigg]^2 -4~ E[X^2]~ E[Y^2] \le 0$$

**Any Ideas?**

Their explanation is something like this: "The discriminant of the quadratic in $\alpha$ appearing in equation must be non-positive, because the quadratic cannot have two distict roots. Therefore:

$$E\Bigg[~2~ \Big|XY\Big|~ \Bigg]^2 -4~ E[X^2]~ E[Y^2] \le 0$$

---

$$ E[|XY|]^2 \le E[X^2]~E[Y^2]$$

$$E[|XY|] \le \sqrt{E[X^2]~E[Y^2]}$$

Comment: Is this true?  Say $X,Y$ were independent.  Is it true in that case?

Comment: are you taking about this:  $E[|XY|] = \sqrt{E[X^2] + E[Y^2]}$
 when you ask is it true?

Comment: I am just looking at the claim in the header.  Suppose $Y=X$. Are you claiming that $E[X^2]=\sqrt {E[X^2]+E[X^2]}$?

Comment: sorry, i'm not seeing that...  maybe you need to refresh your browser..

Comment: @lulu I think he wanted to write $\leq$ instead of $=$ (which is what is being proved also).

Comment: ahh... ok... I didn't notice that mistake,

Comment: @sudeep5221  That's one problem.  I believe he also meant to write a product instead of a sum.  The question is kind of a mess.

Comment: @pico If a quadratic equation in $\alpha$ is positive for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then it implies it does not have any real root. Since it does not have any real root, we can conclude that the discriminant is negative.

Comment: @lulu Oh right I didn't notice that. You're correct. It needs to be edited.

Comment: that means the roots are complex?  what's a discriminant?

Comment: ahh... so if alpha is negative, then it has real roots... is that the idea?

Comment: As Lulu points out, the desired inequality $E[|XY|]\leq \sqrt{E[X^2] + E[Y^2]}$ is untrue in general, take $X=Y$ it reduces to $E[X^2] \leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{E[X^2]}$ which implies $\sqrt{E[X^2]} \leq \sqrt{2}$, which is untrue in general.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(\alpha)=\alpha^2 ~E\Big[X^2\Big] - 2~ \alpha~ E\Big[~|XY|~\Big] + E\Big[Y^2\Big] \ge 0
\tag{1}
$$
here you have quadratic function, so it's discriminant is
$$
\Delta=b^2-4ac=E\Bigg[~2~ \Big|XY\Big|~ \Bigg]^2 -4~ E[X^2]~ E[Y^2].
$$
By (1), $f$ has at most one root, so $\Delta\leq0$.